# How do I legally bring fuel to my empty car in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, car

My car is 2km away from the nearest petrol station, but is completely empty. I really don't want to push it manually there. Therefore my questions:

1. Is it legal at all to buy fuel (unleaded) at petrol station without a car?
2. Can I pour fuel into a random container like plastic 5 litre water bottle?
3. If answer to 2nd question is "no", then what is the quickest way of buying a jerrycan?

Comment: I can't comment on the UK but in the US at least you can't buy fuel in a random can. It must be a proper gasoline-holding can. I have bought one at a gas station before.

Comment: This question is not related to expatriatism at all. Btw you need to have a properly approved container (either plastic or metal) you can buy petrol in. Most bigger petrol stations actually sell them as well in their shops.

Comment: I have done this repeatedly in Essex.  The petrol station even sells the fuel canisters.  It's not an overly big deal.